# Customising tab indicator on android

Tags: android, xml, tabs, navigation

So i currently have my action bar layout using the action bar generator  from

> http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

I would like to know what the best way to customize the tab indicator, specifically its height(make it thinner). Like the example below
notice the very thin tab indicator.

[image]

Thank you all responses appreciated